# Call query in Access 2007 from macro in Excel 2007

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I have a database, that is linked to the CSV file. The name of the database is **AllInformation**, stored at the path = **some_path**. In **AllInformation**, I have a query (named **MyQuery**) with the parameter. Its name is **[Current date]**, the type of the latter is date.

1) How can I connect to the data base - **AllInformation** from the Excel VBA code (I am using Excel 2007)? The data base, **AllInformation**, doesn't have any password. 
2) How can I run the query - **MyQuery** with the setted parameter **[Current date]**?
3) How can I copy the results of **MyQuery** into the Excel sheet?

I need this because searching in the CSV file directly is very time consuming. **MyQuery** finds what I need during 4 minutes, while direct searching via VBA in CSV file will take approx 1 hour.

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: Check this out: http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=91639   It provides the basics of what you need.

Answer (score 0):

As a side note, chances are the code you wrote to search the CSV file directly has some design problem that makes it very inefficient to be getting search times that are that different.

That said, do the following:

1. Add a reference to the Access database engine to the Excel VBA project. In Office 2010 that would be a reference to `Microsoft Office 14.0 Access database engine Object Library`. This library provides a DAO based interface to the Access database engine.
2. Look up how to use DAO on Google. Look up how to run a query with parameters.
3. Also look up how to copy a DAO recordset into an Excel spreadsheet.

These are common tasks you are asking about. You should be able to find numerous answers online if you spend a few seconds searching. I've provided enough information that you should be able to find the answers.

Answer (score 0):

I've worked out this from Excel VBA, querying Access 2007 X.accdb file:

```
'
' Variables:
'   i: counter
'   j: counter
'   nFlds: number of fields in the query
'   nMax: maximum number of records to be exported, 0=no limit
'   strQry: query name
'
'   objApp: Access.Application
'   qdf: QueryDef
'   rst: Recordset
'
Function daoDoQuery()
'
  Dim i, j, nFlds, nMax, strQry
'
  Dim objApp, qdf
  Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
'
  Set objApp = CreateObject("Access.Application")
  objApp.OpenCurrentDatabase "some_path\AllInformation.accdb"
'
' get Recordset:
'
  strQry = "MyQuery"
  Set qdf = objApp.CurrentDb.QueryDefs(strQry)
'
' here [Current date] is entered:
'
  qdf.Parameters(0).Value = Now()
  Set rst = qdf.OpenRecordset(dbOpenDynaset)
'
  If (rst.EOF) Then
    Set rst = Nothing
    daoDoQuery = 0
    Exit Function
  End If
'
  nFlds = rst.Fields.Count
'
' create a new Excel Workbook to write results:
'
  i = 1
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Workbooks.Add
  For j = 1 To nFlds
    With Cells(i, j)
      .Font.Bold = True
      .Font.Size = 12
      .Value = rst.Fields(j - 1).Name
    End With
  Next
'
  nMax = 50
  i = i + 1
'
  Do While (Not rst.EOF)
    '
    For j = 1 To nFlds
      Cells(i, j).Value = rst(j - 1)
    Next
    '
    rst.MoveNext
    i = i + 1
    If (nMax > 0) Then
      If (i > nMax) Then
        Exit Do
      End If
    End If
  Loop
'
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
'
  rst.Close
  Set rst = Nothing
  Set qdf = Nothing
  Set objApp = Nothing
'
  daoDoQuery = 1
'
End Function
```

This will do the job, il will create a new Excel Workbook, with the 1st Worksheet as listing of results:

```
daoDoQuery
```

Comment: @mr.M, a new version using DAO methods for your check.